# How do you detect if a specific word is at the end of a the_title()

Tags: php, query-string

I have event listings that look like this

```
PAPA ROACH AT THE PARAMOUNT IN HUNTINGTON ON APR 28, 2015
```

Im trying to remove everything after the last "ON"

```
$s = the_title();
echo substr($s, 0, strrpos($s, 'ON') - 1);
```

The code above works if '$s' is a regular string but if it is 'the_title()' it does not work. Is there a way to convert the_title() in to a static string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `post` variable to access the `post_title`

```
global $post;
$s = $post->post_title;
echo substr($s, 0, strrpos($s, 'on') - 1);
```

Comment: get_the_title() does not work.

Comment: Code updated with global variable usage.

Comment: Glad I could help :) BTW You already accepted the answer and it got me +15 and now reverted back. Yes! Try again later.

Answer (score -1):

The function you need to use is

```
get_the_title()
```

Comment: Please try to expand this answer by explaining why your code should help.